# How can I convert date format in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

How can I `convert` date format in SQL Server 2008?

```
SELECT 
   Dateadd(DAY, (SELECT MaxCheckday
                 FROM tbl_LibryMemberCategory
                 WHERE IsDeleted = 'N'), Getdate())
```

While running the above query I get this error

> Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
>   The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Comment: can you edit the question with result of `select MaxCheckday from tbl_LibryMemberCategory where IsDeleted='N'`and there is no format converstion happening in your query.

Comment: What is the return data type of MaxCheckDay?

Comment: MAXCHECKDAY IS RETURN "7 DAYS" VAIUES

Comment: I guess you are doing this `convert(varchar,Getdate(),103)` in Dateadd

Comment: MAXCHECKDAY should be numeric 7 only not string "7 DAYS" see corrected query in my answer.

Comment: What is the datatype of the column MaxCheckday in your table? and what value it returned when you run this subquery (SELECT MaxCheckday
                     FROM   tbl_LibryMemberCategory
                     WHERE  IsDeleted = 'N'),,, pls tell those to get your answer or suggestions

Comment: maxcheckday int datatype

Comment: maxcheckday i am define days

Comment: SELECT      DATEADD(DD,  (select MaxCheckday from tbl_LibryMemberCategory where IsDeleted='N'),
convert(varchar(20),GETDATE(),103)) "Show Current date and after 7 days date also can show

Comment: You should make your question clear. Please edit your question and explain further

Answer (score 0):

MaxCheckDay should be 7 only, not "7 DAYS".

```
 SELECT Dateadd(dd,(SELECT MaxCheckday
             FROM   tbl_LibryMemberCategory
             WHERE  IsDeleted = 'N'), Getdate())
```

Comment: You cannot use single quotes in `Datepart` argument and this will not solve OP's problem btw not my DV. FYI you don't have to use `Double quotes` also in Datepart argument

Comment: SELECT      DATEADD(DD,  (select MaxCheckday from tbl_LibryMemberCategory where IsDeleted='N'),
convert(varchar(20),GETDATE(),103)) "ERROR GIVEN"

Comment: Sorry bout that ok try it now

Comment: DATEADD (datepart , number , date ) ===> problem is in second variable(not in first and third),,, so pls modify your answer accordongly

Comment: included that in answer MaxCheckDay should be 7 only, not "7 DAYS". I do not have control in  OP's data

Comment: select MaxCheckday from tbl_LibryMemberCategory this query i am access 7 only interger values

Answer (score 0):

If am not wrong this is what you are trying to achieve

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), Dateadd(Day, MaxCheckday, Getdate()), 103)
FROM   tbl_LibryMemberCategory
WHERE  IsDeleted = 'N'
```

Problem in your query is performing `Dateadd` after the Convertion. Try running the below you will get the same error

```
SELECT Dateadd(day,1, convert(varchar,Getdate(),103))
```

Comment: OP ask he need conversion not resulting rows

Comment: @agentpx what is the use of converting inside `Dateadd` Function

Comment: SELECT      DATEADD(DD,  (select MaxCheckday from tbl_LibryMemberCategory where IsDeleted='N'),
convert(varchar(20),GETDATE(),103))"This subquery also used "

Comment: So my answer is correct? Then mark below as answered

Comment: @agentpx - No it is wrong try running this query `SELECT Dateadd(day,1, convert(varchar,Getdate(),103)) ` even your query is doing the same thing

Comment: You are right I checked it in query analyzer now. @NoDisplayName

Comment: @agentpx - Looks fine